# Explanation needed on boolean methods return

Tags: java, android

I've been looking through some code from a decompiled APK file and ran across this syntax for returning a boolean condition that I haven't seen before.  Anyone have an explanation on how this works?

```
public static boolean is2G(NetworkType paramNetworkType)
{
    if ((EDGE.equals(paramNetworkType)) || (IDEN.equals(paramNetworkType)) || (CDMA.equals(paramNetworkType)) || (GPRS.equals(paramNetworkType)));
    for (int i = 1; ; i = 0)
        return i;
}
```

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile...

Comment: As a general rule, if you took decompiled code and tried to compiled it and it didn't work, there was an error in the decompile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This composed conditions means if any or all of these 4 conditions are true the whole condition is true.

But the condition body is empty, so nothing happens afterwards. The loop is nevertheless executed independent of the condition.

But you should also be aware that the decompiling is sometimes not working exactly, so maybe it is a decompiling error. This assumption is even more true if you look at the incorrect return type. So even if this code is widely used through the whole application I would suggest a decompiling problem.

Comment: No it doesn't. Mind the semi-colon at the end of the if()

Comment: This syntax was used heavily throughout the entire application in many spots.

Comment: I guess so, its just odd that there isn't any identifiable obfuscation in the rest of the app.  Possible a bad decompile.. (was using dex2jar)

Comment: I'm also using dex2jar and I noticed that it does its job really well but sometimes there are errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is weird.

The condition doesn't do anything at all. It's like

```
if (condition) {
}
```

The loop condition says "execute forever"

The loop body says "return right away", but it's returning THE WRONG TYPE!!! How can this even compile?